# How to String include after character in nodejs, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to do this in `node.js`

example.js

```
var str = "a@universe.dev";
var n = str.includes("b@universe.dev");
console.log(n);
```

but with restriction, so it can search for that string only after the character in this example `@` so if the new search string would be `c@universe.dev` it would still find it as the same string and outputs `true` because it's same "domain" and what's before the character in this example everything before `@` would be ignored.

Hope someone can help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `String.prototype.endsWith`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

First, you need to get the end of the first string.

```js
var ending = "@" + str.split("@").reverse()[0];
```

I split your string by the `@` character, so that something like `"abc@def@ghi"` becomes the array `["abc", "def", "ghi"]`. I get the last match by reversing the array and grabbing the first element, but there are multiple ways of doing this. I add the separator character back to the beginning.

Then, check whether your new string ends the same:

```js
var n = str.endsWith(ending);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Very well explained thank you so much! Also, I appreciate your example and the link to the detailed explanation of {String.prototype.endsWith} and how you came to the result ❤

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "a@universe.dev";
var str2 = 'c@universe.dev';

str = str.split('@');
str2 = str2.split('@');

console.log(str[1] ===str2[1]);
```

With split you can split string based on the @ character. and then check for the element on position 1, which will always be the string after @.

Comment: What if we have @ sign multiple times? That won't work

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function

```
function stringIncludeAfterCharacter(s1, s2, c) {
   return s1.substr(s1.indexOf(c)) === s2.substr(s2.indexOf(c));
}
```

then use it

```
console.log(stringIncludeAfterCharacter('a@universe.dev', 'b@universe.dev', '@' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "a@universe.dev";
var n = str.includes(str.split('@')[1]);
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Does not account for multiple "@" characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another way !

```
var str = "a@universe.dev";
var n = str.indexOf(("b@universe.dev").split('@')[1]) > -1;
console.log(n);
```